# CMIS query trying to retrieve folders/files under specific path returns no documents

Tags: java, lucene, alfresco, cmis, opencmis

Greetings to the community! I am using `alfresco community edition 6.0.0` and I just faced a very weird problem. I am using the Java API to access my alfresco repository by running `CMIS` queries. I successfully fetched documents using `cmis-strict` like shown below:

Example 1)

```
select * from cmis:document WHERE cmis:name like '%doc%' AND  cmis:objectId =  'e318a431-0ff4-4a4a-9537-394d2bd761af' "
```

Example 2)

```
SELECT * FROM cmis:document WHERE IN_FOLDER('63958f9c-819f-40f4-bedf-4a2e402f8b9f') AND cmis:name like '%temp%'
```

which work perfectly, what I would like to do is retrieve files/folders under a specific path (**f.e fetch all folders under /app:company_home/app:user_homes**)

what I do is running from the node browser of alfresco the following cmis-strict query

```
SELECT * FROM cmis:folder WHERE CONTAINS('PATH:"//app:company_home/app:user_homes//*"')
```

but **even though there are existing folders under that directory nothing is returned**. It seems that the PATH argument is not recognized as it should does, as when i run the query 
`SELECT * FROM cmis:folder` I get back many results that have as parent the

```
app:company_home/app:user_homes
```

node

Any idea what may be the problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

EDIT:

I have also tried to use lucene query like

```
PATH:"/app:company_home/app:user_homes//*") but no results returned too
```

Answer (score 2):

Your user homes contains query works for me in both 5.2 and 6.1.1.

I like @Lista's suggestion of checking into your index. If that doesn't bear fruit, you might go get the CMIS object ID of the user homes folder, then use it with the IN_FOLDER clause you've already proven works.

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for your response, I already use the method you propose but I would really want to retrieve documents using the path. So I guess I have to perform some kind of indexing in my repository? or in any specific node?

Answer (score 1):

I think both Lucene and CMIS queries (if using CONTAINS) end up on the index (not database), so it's not weird to assume something is off with the index itself. Have you tried rebuilding them? Are your nodes even in index (there's a SOLR admin console you can use to see this)?

https://docs.alfresco.com/6.0/concepts/query-lang-support.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) Where is exactly that SOLR admin console you refer?  In the same section with the Node Browser and Workflow console?

Comment: No, this is a separate application.
https://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/ssl-protect-solrwebapp.html

Comment: Thanks for the resources, will check it out :)